# Off heap runs out of memory. Does profiler show off heap objects?

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory

The application's heap size is fine and objects get garbage collected as expected.  However, the off-heap size keeps growing and eventually the VM crashes.

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> SIGBUS (0x7) at pc=  , pid=  , tid=
>
> Problematic frame:

Does profiler such as JProfiler shows what's in the off heap and how they got allocated? How best to troubleshoot?

I am looking at the heap walker of JProfiler but not sure if there is anyway to see what's in the off heap.

Appreciate your help!
-G

Comment: You need to examine the native components you are using. Forcing a heap dump may allow you to see java objects which refer to native memory. The problematic frame which you did not include, may include hints as to native components being used.